# Hiding Chrome WebDriver in a console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to hide the chrome windows opened with Selenium WebDriver in C# console application?

Answer (score 2):

There does appear to be a workaround for this.

Specifically, the [**CreateNoWindow**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) Property.

By default it's value is `false`, but try setting it to `true`.

Inside the `Start()` method in your `WebDriver\DriverService.cs`

You'd place it like so:

```
this.driverServiceProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Comment: Beware of doing this without using the full build process for the Selenium project. Simply building in Visual Studio will not give you an equivalent assembly to that generated by the Selenium project's build script.